# C programming output specifications for counting answers

Tags: c

I'm taking a basic programming class and we can do practice programs as we go to better ourselves. Right now, I'm trying to write a program that uses a while loop to ask for inputs from a user then the program decides if those inputs meets a certain value or not. The trouble I'm having with is the output.
For example, "You have met this certain number X times out of Y times."
What do you use to keep track of how many inputs was put in and how many met the criteria?

Answer (score 1):

Typically you'd use a pair of `int` variables for that.  Initialize both to zero, then increment one each time through the loop that reads the input (so it counts how many inputs there were), and increment the other within an `if` statement that checks whether the input meets the criteria (so it counts how many inputs met the criteria).  At the end of the loop, the two variables hold the numbers that you want to print.